# ASP.NET MVC calling a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to pass already existing model into a method from my partial, the problem is that (it looks like) this syntax

`@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeOverallReportFilter", "Reports", FormMethod.Post)) {}`

is recreating my model, because my controller is receiving model with data only from edit-boxes inside `@using {}`

In other words:

1. `new Model`
2. Add some data&doMagic and go to my partial
3. In my partial add more data and pass it to the controller
4. Work with data

And i have the problem in step 3, because some how (i think because of `@using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeOverallReportFilter", "Reports", FormMethod.Post)) {}`) i am losing data added in step 2.

The question is:

Is it true? Can `@using (Html.BeginForm()) {}` re-create my model or should i add all code?

There is some other way to call a method and pass data there?

I have tried this :
 `<input type="submit" onclick="@Html.Action("EmployeeOverallReportFilter", "Reports", Model)" />`

But the error :

`Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'EmployeeOverallReportFilter' was not found on controller 'BTGHRM.Controllers.ReportsController'.`

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EmployeeOverallReportFilter(EmployeeOverallReport model)
    {
        //foreach(var item in model.ListOfPersonalData)
        //{
        //    //NameFiler
        //    if((!item.FirstName.Contains(model.ModelFilters.NameFilter)) && model.ModelFilters.NameFilter!=String.Empty) model.ListOfPersonalData.Remove(item);
        //}
        return View("EmployeeOverAllReport", model);
    }
```

Comment: A form only posts back the values of its successful controls. If you have previously saved some associated data, add its ID in a roure value or hidden input so you post it and can retrieve that data in the POST method.

Comment: The error is occurring because you should have a method on your reports Controller called 'EmployeeOverallReportFilter' and it needs to be adorned with `[Post]`. To pass existing data back you need your view model to include properties of the data that you want to keep and in the `[Get]` method you need to set these. Then when you post again, they will go as long as they are part of the form

Comment: You will have to include hidden fields for all the properties that you want to be posted back along with the data entered by user in the form.

Comment: @Div Added method that will receive data. This one you were asking for?

Comment: @sachin it is a bit complicated model. It looks like
MainModel :

 1. list of models in which i have 3 other lists of models + some props

 2. model with bool props
 3. model with filter props
Do I have to add ALL of them or just those 3 from main model?
It made to allow user to add/remove columns in the table and filter rows.

Comment: When the form is posted, it would have the data that you want the user to supply through the form. You should fetch the rest of data for Model from wherever you store your data.

Comment: @sachin it looks like a lot of code (approximately 100 fields)  . It is not a problem, but still there is other way to send data to controller without losing unused data or mentioning every property?

Comment: One way would be to serialize all the data in a string, post that back in a hidden field and then de-serialize that when form is posted. However, it might be simpler to fetch the Model data from the Data Store. You would want such approach only if you don't have your Model stored elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124770/discussion-between-vadim-k-and-sachin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest create a session and store the existing Model and then equate the new changes into the existing model from the session. If you store all your data on the page using a mechanism like hidden fields it will make your page heavy.

Comment: It looks like a solution, but i have a problem mb you can help me:    
   EmployeeOverallReport give = list;
            @Session["ReportModel"] = give;
(LATER)
            var take = Session["ReportModel"];

The problem is that it cannot conver type `object` into my model's type, and therefore i can't access inner properties in the model.

Comment: var take = (EmployeeOverallReport)Session["ReportModel"];  this should do it.

Comment: Np man, I was also learning once, don't know why people don't remember that.